# Disable syntax highlighting in Geany

Tags: geany, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to turn off syntax highlighting in Geany.

I tried commenting this out in `filetype_extensions.conf`.

```
Sh=*.sh;configure;configure.in;
```

As a temporary fix, I changed file extension of files such as scripts to `txt`.

Comment: You renamed your bash scripts from `___.sh` to `___.txt`??? Lots of people won't even bother with an extension on their bash scripts at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off syntax coloring in Geany](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997373/turn-off-syntax-coloring-in-geany)

Comment: Asked before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/997373/turn-off-syntax-coloring-in-geany

Comment: There's also this abandoned thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382253

Comment: Asked before: askubuntu.com/questions/997373/… – DK Bose Answers there did not not work for me.

Comment: @DKBose since this one has an answer, I'm voting to close the older q as dupe.

Comment: @muru, I added my close vote there.

Comment: And retracted the close vote here.

Comment: As my post said, I temporarily renamed .sh to .txt in order to fool geany so it would not use syntax highlighting. I know I do not need extensions, but it makes it easier to see the file type. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default syntax highlighting colours are defined in /usr/share/geany/filedefs/filetypes.common in the section named

```
[named_styles]
```

You can edit/remove one or more but while some are intuitive as colors like

```
comment=0xd00000
```

there are some that are a bit weird, like

```
selection=0x000000;0xc0c0c0;false;true
```

and I have no idea what they really mean. So it's a case of trial and error, but you can get to a simple white on black theme eventually by removing them.

If you just wanted to disable syntax highlighting for certain file types, there is a mechanism which allows you to overwrite the themes for each file type, but it's tedious. The individual file type configuration files are in the same directory.

But for your purpose, you just want to hack the [named_styles] section in the common conf file which will nuke syntax highlighting in all file types.

EDIT: The other method suggested to you, i.e. removing the file extension from Menu->tools->configuration files->filetype_extensions.conf will have the effect of removing all functionality the ide provides for those file types, while the method I suggested directly affects only the syntax highlighting. But it's up to you which method you adopt, depending on your ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than renaming your `.sh` scripts with an `.txt` extension there is a more conventional way to [remove syntax highlighting](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1596):

Edit `Menu->tools->configuration files->filetype_extensions.conf` and remove the `*.sh`; entries.

Comment: Removing the *.sh entries did not work. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: The link also refers to one user having to set `none` as well.

Comment: I have all syntax turned off except any thing in double quotes. @nobody special You are right, Geany is weird.

Comment: Send email to one of Geany's authors.

Comment: To turn off syntax highlighting just for .sh files set string=default in filetypes.sh